# Can I RSA-encrypt in Java but decrypt in PHP?

Tags: java, php, encryption, rsa

Can I RSA-encrypt in J2ME or J2SE, and decrypt in PHP?

I assume RSA is a specification, and has nothing to do with the languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in a word, yes.

the only problem you might run into is character encoding or line-endings, but chances are you'll be fine.

Answer (score 4):

RSA is an algorithm; the other thing you need in order to interoperate is a specification of the message format.  [RFC 3447](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447) defines one possible message format, there are others, for example [RFC 3110](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3110) DNS key format.  Pick a message format as well, and there should be no problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you are encrypting anything larger than a key, you may want to consider encrypting your data with a symmetric cipher then encrypting the symmetric key using RSA. The standard mechanism for doing this (used in S/MIME etc) is [CMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_Message_Syntax) (The IETF's update to PKCS#7). I'm not sure what support there is for CMS/PKCS#7 in PHP but on the java side you can use the excellent [bouncy castle crypto library](http://www.bouncycastle.org/). You will have no interoperability problems as all the data structures are defined in ASN.1. Don't worry if it sounds a bit complicated as these details are abstracted away for you by the crypto library.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I do that. In Java, any JCE should do. In PHP, please use OpenSSL extension.

As others mentioned, you can only encrypt up to key_length - 11 bytes. For example, for a 1024-bit key, you can only encrypt 117 bytes. If your data may exceed that, please use PKCS#7 which is supported by OpenSSL extension.

Comment: J2ME does not include the JCE.